# Materual UI Label overlap with value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently using v1.0.0-beta.6 (https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/text-field/) and it appears that the label will overlap with value if it is set by javascript on mount, even if I set `autoFocus={true}` (though it does auto-focus for a second or so, it quickly reverts back).

```
class TestTextField extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {this._input.value = 'Some Value'}
  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
        label="Label 1"
        autoFocus={true}
        inputRef={(elem) => {this._input = elem}}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

[image: overlap image]

I know for MaterializeCSS, a material design framework that uses JQuery, they have a method to call `Materialize.updateTextFields()` to manually update fields with issues like this, but is there such a method here?

Comment: Why are you setting the property in `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: `this._input` is undefined when the component hasn't mounted yet, and in my full application I'm setting the values given from `props` received from an AJAX request.